# amazon aws-s3 access denied error

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip

I wanted to integrate amazon s3 service with my rails application.
I am using paperclip(2.3.6) gem and aws-s3(0.6.2) gem for this. but as the user uploads a file,
It throws an error Access denied.
I am able to put and get the file if i am trying from rails console. using the same credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set up the **ACL permissions**?

http://www.bucketexplorer.com/ is a good tool for it.

There are several S3 clients in all OS's.

Comment: Removed earlier downvote. It looks like you need extra permissions to create something with `:public_read` ACL, which is what Paperclip uses by default.