# How to fix 'Access Denied' error with a .Net WCF service running on Amazon EC2?

Tags: wcf, web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-4.0

I am new to the AWC/EC2 environment and created a .Net WCF service on my EC2 instance of Windows Server and IIS.

Navigating to http://www.websiteservice.com/MyWebsiteFeederService.svc?wsdl brings up the WSDL.

Now, in www.mywebsite.com, that is also sitting on the same machine, I have consumed the web service.  Unfortunately whenever I try to access the service through the site, I continue to receive the "Access is Denied" error message:

> Exception Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is
>   denied.

I don't believe this is related to the [AWS-S3 error - Access is Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322187/amazon-aws-s3-access-denied-error) error, as I am not using buckets.

In the site's Web.config, I turned on the trace listener and took a look at the Service Trace Viewer.

The information doesn't seem to be useful, as this is what I get:

> [TraceRecord] Severity    Warning
>   TraceIdentifier   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx
>   Description   Throwing an exception.
>   AppDomain /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-2-129966419874659765

Here is the full XML of Warning level:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Warning">0</SubType>
<Level>4</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-11-06T02:19:47.8029428Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{b6efab70-63ad-4bdd-85c6-5c49a907c210}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="3472" ThreadID="1" />
<Channel />
<Computer>AMAZONA-xxxxxFFR</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-2-129966419874659765</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Access is denied.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
at MyWebsiteFeederService.IFeederService.GetWebsiteConfiguration(String websiteGuid, String websitePW)
at MyWebsiteFeederService.FeederServiceClient.GetWebsiteConfiguration(String websiteGuid, String websitePW)
at Inquiro.Models4.ModelsBaseClass.GetWebsiteConfiguration(String websiteGuid, String websitePW)
at Inquiro.Websites.MvcApplication.LoadWebsiteConfiguration()
at Inquiro.Websites.MvcApplication.Application_Start()
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct&amp; sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert(MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest(HttpContext context, MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs, HttpSessionState session)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.</ExceptionString>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

I have the exact same service running on another, non-Amazon server and it is working fine.  I don't recall setting up any special permissions, or "run as [user]" - have no additional users setup in IIS Manager Permissions.

I have also confirmed from the command prompt on that server, using sqlcmd, that I can connect to the RDS database server.

I'm basically going in circles at this point and would appreciate some assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error itself "Access is denied." isn't very helpful.  Neither is the debug information.

Ultimately, in this case, the issue was that execute permissions needed to be granted to the userID that was executing the stored procedures called from the WCF service.

Comment: did you use the following to do so? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735120(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: To modify user privilege levels, use the following steps.

Click Start and then Run and type compmgmt.msc.

Right-click Services and Application/WMI Controls to select Properties.

Select the Security Tab, and navigate to the Root/ServiceModel namespace. Click the Security button.

Select the specific group or user that you want to control access and use the Allow or Deny checkbox to configure permissions.